# Why do some urls in Firefox change when copy / paste?

Tags: firefox

This may not be a Firefox / Ubuntu specific issue.

When I Copy / Paste a web link with _ and ( ) it is rendered as %20, %28, and %29.

Yet in the Firefox URL these % symbols do not appear.

The %20 is particularly weird because the _ itself does render in the URL:

`https://www.capitalsecuritybank.com/en/PDF/CSB_%20Account_%20Application_%20Form_%20%28Personal%29.pdf`

Can anyone explain why the URL is different when Copied / Pasted?

Comment: `%HH` where `H`s are hexadecimals are url-encoded versions of `(`, `)` and _`. Same for spaces (`%20`). See wikipedia.

Comment: @Lekensteyn provide them a link to that, and make that an answer?

Comment: How to avoid it: http://superuser.com/questions/480692/copying-unicode-symbols-from-firefox-address-bar-as-is

Answer (score 4):

This is because of encoding to UTF-8 to make sure hyperlinks (and other contained data in the URL) work even though they contain symbols or country specific letters. You can read more about this on http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm if you are interested.

If you just want to get rid of it, there's an easy solution. Go to `about:config` and set the following line

> network.standard-url.escape-utf8: false

This should fix your encoding of links.

Comment: The information provided about the `about:config` option is incorrect, it only applies to UTF-8 characters. Try opening http://example.com/foo%20meh%E1%88%B4 for example. You will see that the last character turns into `ሴ` while the space is still percent-encoded. This happens because that is the standard, valid URLs do not contain spaces (otherwise text would be ambiguous, did you mean `http://example.com/page is awesome` as URL? Or `"http://example.com/page" is awesome`?